# How should I write SQL query that contains LIKE in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to make a query that ends in `LIKE value%`, but for some reason, there is an error with it.

`$_GET['letter']` contains the starting letter that I want to use in my query.

For example if its `'a'`, my query will be `...WHERE name LIKE 'a%'`.

My code:

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT id, name, username, email FROM users WHERE name LIKE '" . ($_GET['letter']) . "%'");
```

The error I get is: `PHP Warning:  sprintf(): Too few arguments`

And then of course: `PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Empty query`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: <scream>Injecting a $_GET var directly into a SQL query</scream>

Comment: Also, since this seems to be user input you need to secure the data (SQL Injection).

Comment: I just oversimplified the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't even consider taking this route. Use prepared statements with PDO or mysqli instead.

```
if(isset($_GET['letter']) && strlen($_GET['letter']) > 0) {
    $letter = $_GET['letter'] . '%';
    $sql = "SELECT id, name, username, email FROM users WHERE name LIKE ?";
    $query = $con->prepare($sql);
    $query->bind_param('s', $letter);
    $query->execute();

    $query->bind_result($id, $name, $username, $email);
    while($query->fetch()) {
        echo $id . '<br/>';
        // and others
    }

    // alternate version with mysqlnd installed
    // $results = $query->get_result();
    // while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    //  echo $row['id'];
    // }
} else {
    echo 'please provide for search value';
}
```

Comment: At least add something like `if (strlen($_GET['letter']) == 1) {...}`! And add some more words of warning.

Comment: Thank you! Now I need the quicker solution, but I'm planning on using prepared queries.

Comment: @aarminofficial i just showed how it went wrong, but no, there is no excuse not to use this way, always make sure of you have safe queries to execute

Comment: Using `sprintf` is a terrible idea, as you point out. It's not even worth mentioning because people might think this is easier when actually it's not. There's a massive SQL injection hole there that's not obvious because of the substitution being made. You should remove that part of the answer completely as people tend to run with the first thing that works.

Comment: @tadman yeah you have a good point there, they might think this is an okay way of dealing with this but in fact the worst idea.

Comment: Come on, hurl that thing into the sun, don't just stroke it out. Every day I see news headlines of companies being forced to apologize for leaking everyone's personal information because of careless mistakes like that. It's sitting on top of a perfectly good answer like an awful toupee.